# Optimizing a SQL query with a ranged WHERE clause against a large table

Tags: sql

I have a database table that has three columns: an ID, a timestamp, and a string.  About 14,000 rows are inserted every day, so the table is very large.  It currently has 1.3 million rows.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE readings (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  ts datetime not null, --the timestamp
  json text not null --the string
);
```

The query I'm running is:

```
SELECT * FROM readings WHERE ts >= 'TIME_START' AND ts <= 'TIME_END' ORDER BY ts
```

The query takes around 45 seconds to execute.  How can I modify the table and/or query to make it faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new index on `ts` to the table.

Comment: I thought indexes only worked when you specify a specific value of a column, not a range of values.  For example: `WHERE ts = 'TIME'`

Comment: @Michael: It may depend on the database, but I would normally expect this to work for most databases. Performance would be still better for a specific value, but a range of values should work (provided the range is not too wide) - I have actually had a real-life example of this (on an Oracle database) where the query performance dropped from approx 60 seconds, to under a second.

Comment: At which point is the range considered "too wide"?  Do you think MySQL supports this?

Comment: @Michael: I'm not an expert at optimising MySQL queries, but I think it ought to work. As I understand it, MySQL uses a cost-based optimiser; I suspect that a range of one day (or less) ought to work fine, but a range of one year would probably cause the optimiser to do a table scan instead. My best advice is to try it and see.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  The range is limited to a max of 1 week, so looks like I shouldn't have problems.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes into my mind are [partitions](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/195905/Tips-and-Tricks-to-Optimize-MySQL) assuming you set everything right. You also might want to try different database engine (eg. InnoDB). Or setting up an index in the ts column.

Other than that - using >= <= vs BETWEEN doesn't make any performance impact so don't worry with that.

Comment: Thanks, might try partitioning by month.

Answer (score 0):

You can just order the results with your primary id which is autoincrement.

Comment: The ID and timestamps aren't aligned.  In other words, it's not true that the higher the ID the higher the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query.. if the index is on id this might be faster

```
declare @min_id as int
declare @max_id as int

select @min_id = min(id)
from readings WHERE ts = 'TIME_START' 

select @max_id = max(id)
from readings WHERE ts = 'TIME_END'

SELECT * FROM readings  
id between @min_id and @max_id order by id
```

Comment: The IDs and timestamps aren't aligned, so it's not true that the higher the ID the higher the timestamp.

Comment: then you need go back to order by ts but he query should still run faster since the condition is on id which might be your index

Comment: If I make `ts` an index, will that help?

Comment: it depends on your scenario... you can use id as the clustered index and ts as non clustered.. if you are using this query..